# Differential equation with 3 variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I've been solving a physics problem from the internet and I end up with the following:
[image]
I've tried substituting and taking derivatives twice but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. My aim is to find $t$ when $s=0$ and the initial condition is when, $t=0, \theta=60, s=1$. Any hints would be really appreciated.

**Edit Note:** Both $\theta$ and $s$ are decreasing with time.

Comment: I don't think that this little monster will have any closed-form expression. Numerical integration is the way. (Just the nonlinearity on $\theta$ makes it harder than the pendulum equation, and there's additional nonlinearity due to $s$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Be sure that I really do not appreciate the *little* in your comment. It is a **BIG** one. Cheers.

Comment: Could you tell where you did find the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate one of the dependent variables and obtain a single equation of the fourth order:

$$\theta=-0.1\arcsin \ddot s$$

$$\dot\theta=-0.1\dddot s(1-\ddot s^2)^{-1/2}$$

$$\ddot\theta=-0.1\ddddot s(1-\ddot s^2)^{-1/2}+0.1\ddot s\dddot s^2(1-\ddot s^2)^{-3/2}=15(1-0.01\ddot s^2)^{1/2}\frac{2s+1}{1+3s^2}.$$

This doesn't make the monster less BIG.